# Specifying trusted SSL certs in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, authentication

I know that you can do an https request in Python, passing in a cert or bundle to requests.post(), with the verify argument.

Is there any way to do something similar in ArcPy?

I'd like to fully automate some code, but can't get a permanent certificate yet.

Failing that (since I'm on Windows), is there a way to have it check the system trusted certificates?

Answer (score 0):

I would trust the [comment by @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289299/specifying-trusted-ssl-certs-in-arcpy#comment463769_289299) who says that as far as they know:

> ... if the machine trusts it, arcpy will trust it. Meaning arcpy uses
> the system, it doesnt have its own trust mechanism. You're probably
> dealing with self-signed certs? Try installing it into the machines
> trust store:
> https://specopssoft.com/support-docs/specops-password-reset/reference-material/installing-the-self-signed-ssl-certificate-into-the-trusted-root-certificate-authorities-store/